# How to fix this ui using media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

1. I thought like it is overlapping media queries issues but I didn't find any media query which overlaps.
2. I resize the width of menucontainer and searchcontainer but didn't work.
3. I thought it was that searchcontainer which has more size in padding,I tried to decrease and increase the padding value of searchcontainer but it didn't work.
   4.When I click on 'Toggle device toolbar' it is not showing any dislocation of this three container(searchcontainer,contactcontainer and menucontainer) but when I remove 'Toggle device' option that time on chrome view it is dislocated their positions.
4. This dislocation occurs in between 786px to 771px width.
5. I want both side same view and this view can be supported all devices including desktop, tablets .
6. [Click here to understand my code](http://jsfiddle.net/SharminShirgaonkar/9yfgj2sd/14)
7. Here is my code
   `

```css
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 768px), (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) {
.MenuContactContainer {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        vertical-align: top !important;
        padding-right: 0px;
        text-align: center !important;
    }

    .MenuContact {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        vertical-align: central;
        padding-right: 10px;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: large;
        text-align: center !important;
    }
.search-container {
        width: 102% !important;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 55px;
        margin-left: 0px !important;
    }


    .Hamburger {
        z-index: 257;
        width: 465px;
        height: 41px;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
        margin-left: 16px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: -53px;
        position: relative;
        border-color: transparent;
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        background: transparent url(../images/hamburger.png) no-repeat center center;
        background-size: contain;
    }

    .searchtextbox {
        height: 32px;
        background-color: #EAB640;
        padding-left: 10px;
        margin-top: -2px;
        margin-bottom: 18px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 270px;
        margin-left: 32px;
    }
}
```

`

How can I solve this issue? Please me find out that issue.

[This is dislocation of three components are here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYhZc.png)

[This is showing in 'Toggle device' mode which is right position.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Bm5.png)

Comment: Can you share a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to make understand your problem better?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/SharminShirgaonkar/9yfgj2sd/14/ use this and please help me.

Comment: Hi there, can you rephrase your question giving more detail? There is no problem stated in your question.